# Azure Devops permissions - can one area be visible to one team and invisible to another

Tags: azure-devops, permissions, visibility, area, azure-boards

In my Azure boards, I have a hierarchical structure of the areas. In the team settings, all teams have areas being set, just like described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/safe-configure-boards?view=azure-devops#configure-area-paths

Is there a way for one team to see only the area it is set to, but no other areas? Currently, in Boards>Work items any member of any team can see everything, even User stories that do not belong to his area. How can I restrict this?

Edit: it might be from Security options of an area, add a group to it and make work items invisible, see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6x8Oy.jpg) from Azure documentation.
But, even as an admin, I don't have such option to add! Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

The UI has changed. There is no **add** option in the security settings page now.
You can directly search for the Team Group in the Search box and change its permission settings. See below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, in addition to Levi's answer:

First, every new user added to a project is also added by default to one of this project's groups: Contributors, Readers, Admins. I'm not considering admins here.

If we want to make one area visible to only one team, we need to do the following:

1. Either modify Contributors or Readers rights so that the "View project-level information" is set to Deny, and then for each new user, add it to a team and for that team set this option to Allow for the area needed

or (better)

2. Create our own groups for which "View project-level information" is set to Deny (for ex. Developers, QAs, etc.), and then for each new user, remove it from Contributors or Readers and add it to the corresponding group. Then add the user to a team, and for that team set the "View project-level information" option to Allow for the area needed